# How to Display a working but dummy progress bar in java

Tags: java, progress-bar

I want to show a progress bar in my java program but I dont want it to actually work on a real task but i want it to just show that some process is being completed and it should look as if some process is going on. I tried to do this with the following code but it isn't helping me, so please if u can help....

Code:

```
       try 
       {
           for(int i=0;i<=100;i++){
              prog.setValue(i); // this would set the progressbar
             Thread.sleep(300); // this should pause the program or the loop
           }
       }

       catch(Exception e){

       }
```

Comment: do you know how to use Swing ? or you mean a console bar?

Comment: ok let me clear myself, i am actually importing my database into mysql through a command button and what i want is that when the user click on the button a progress bar will be displayed which will show the dummy progress not the actual one...

Comment: btw, i am using netbeans for my program

Comment: You're problem is not in this part of the code. This should work as expected: monitor the progress of a "sleeping application" (unless someone interrupts the sleeping thread, because that exception is catched and eaten outside of the loop. What exactly *is not working*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming Swing...

Put the progress bar in *indeterminate mode*
A progress bar in indeterminate mode displays animation to indicate that work is occurring

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html#indeterminate

Comment: i dont think u got my question.
I want to display the progress bar, progressing from 0 to 100.
So how to do that??

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that shows a progress bar going from 0 to 100. It is important to update the progress bar on the event dispatching thread using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` or `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait`.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar(0,100);
        f.add(bar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.setSize(64, 64);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);

        for(int i = bar.getMinimum(); i <= bar.getMaximum(); i++){
            final int percent = i ;
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    bar.setValue(percent);
                }
            });
            try {
                Thread.sleep(25);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int progressCounter=0;

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (progressCounter <= 100) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        jProgressBar1.setValue(jProgressBar1.getValue()+1);
                        System.err.println("hello");
                    }
                });
                try { Thread.sleep(500); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Try this, it will definitely work. In java components are updated using EDT and `invokeLater(Runnable)` is used to call a task when every other task in the block has been completed.